# Coconut Climbing Machine Ideas

Tags: mechanical-engineering, robotics, mechanical-failure

I have been trying to create a machine to climb coconuts as the existing machines are very slow and strenuous to use and frankly, most climbers prefer to climb it manually than use the existing machine, which all more or less use the same concept of the image given below

(Search Google for more).

I wanted to automate that process to make it easier and faster. 
[image: Coconut Climber]

I have been experimenting with machines and designs like using circular drums and powering them, using raised platforms attached to vehicles but none of them have properly materialized. So now after many futile attempts, I turn to the engineering community to help me and suggest new ideas on their own.

I am new to this and I don't know if I can ask such a question. 
But still I just wanted to try. Give me any ideas if you can. If you feel that this is not appropriate, please comment below and I will correct it.

Thank You

Comment: Please also search how native Filipinos climb coconuts. :) They use cloth-like cord to wrap around coconuts and into their feet. It is quite useful and simple as the friction generated by the cord is sufficient to hold them in place.

Comment: That's how everyone does it, not just native Filipinos @JemEripol. It can be done that way but now labour is becoming increasingly costly and the number of people are also decreasing.

Comment: @JemEripol surely they climb the trees not the coconuts - unless they are very large....

Comment: How about genetically modifying the tree so it stays short.....

Comment: @JemEripol I don't think you understand. That is the standard way. By using a cloth like cord. These machines are being not being used that much. That is what I meant when i said "prefer to climb it manually".

Comment: Oh I see. Another way we use is we cut steps on the coconut tree itself. Then step on it. :) not sure if it is healthy for the coconut. @StrangePhoton, I am getting the classic way to improvise the method. Maybe you can get some ideas from ice tongs

Comment: dwarf plants have their own downfalls like being infected easily by ground pests and the quality and quantity of yield is not very high as compared to tall varieties @SolarMike

Comment: Just an idea .......

Comment: You can also share this question to http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com

Comment: No it is not healthy as it start shedding sap  and it is not practical to cut steps into the tree as it will fill back. So we have to cut steps into it very time  we climb. Imagine cut steps into 70 trees (which is the number that can be planted in an acre). To climb the 30m tall coconut you have to cut steps at every 200 cm (which by itself is the max) which means you have to cut out 150 steps. So for an acre you have to cut 150*70 = 10,500 steps. Most farmers have 30 to 40 acres. So they have to cut 4,20,000 steps for 40 acres and they fill up. So they have to cut 8 (min)times each year cont

Comment: which is 4,20,000 * 8 = 33,60,000 steps every year. Imagine that to cut each step  you would need atleast 1 minutes to cut a step which is 3 million minutes which is 2333 days every year

Comment: That will be possible if there is only **one** farmer to take care of the 40 acres of coconut trees. That means he will be the **ONLY** one to climb it all up?

Comment: Most usually farms 40 acre farms can be managed by 5 people as coconut farms don't need intensive labour. So even if 10 people do it it will take 233 days to cut the steps @JemEripol

Comment: And 40 acres of coconut farms can actually be managed by one person and there are people who do it. It is only during harvesting time that daily labours are employed to climb and harvest the coconuts.

Comment: Oh, I see. Then step cutting is not efficient in your end. I did not see that as too much because I had witnessed my grandfather single-handedly take care of our 8 hectare (20 acres) of coconut plantation on his own while he did the step-cutting in each trees. :) I don't know how exactly he did it though.

Comment: Brainstorming / discussion based questions are off-topic for the site.

Answer (score 1):

How about a "**Cherry Picker**" type machine?  They are readily available for hire or purchase in most countries and come in all shapes and sizes...

Edit: Apparently I am not allowed to post pictures of cherry picker machines here  :(

A small machine with outrigger legs and a small diesel motor could easily (and safely) allow access to the treetops and might even be faster than manual climbing.

Placing the machine equidistantly between two or more adjacent trees might make it feasible to harvest from multiple trees without moving the machine (the hydraulic arm can pivot 360 degrees around the fixed base).

Comment: can be considered. have to check the costs too @wossname